# Heroku Node.js Remote Mysql Database IP Address

Tags: mysql, node.js, heroku

I have a remote Mysql database that I am connecting to through Node.js on Heroku. My MySql host (bluehost) wants me to input IP Adresses of all remote MySql connections.

Heroku doesn't have a dedicated IP for my app, so how can I connect to it? Bluehost mentions something about a Class C IP on its page, but I'm not sure Heroku has one...

Also, I believe I already have all of the heroku environment variables set up correctly:

(`heroku config:add EXTERNAL_DATABASE_URL=...`)

Thanks :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what blue host says about dynamic ip addresses:

#### Dynamic IP Addresses

> Having a dynamic IP address means that the connecting IP address can
> change periodically depending on the Internet Service Provider (ISP).
> You must update the connecting IP in Remote MySQL every time it
> changes.

from https://my.bluehost.com/cgi/help/89.

So at least each time you redeploy your application, you have a chance to get a different ip address.  So this seems highly impractical.  Why don't you use Heroku's MySQL offering?

Comment: You're right. I think I'll just use Heroku's MySQL or maybe their PostgreSQL stuff. Thanks, though :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use one of 'static ip' addons and proxy connection via that static ip - see [this discussion](https://github.com/felixge/node-mysql/issues/725)